# jquery accordion Expand while page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

jquery accordion should open while page loading.
after page loading complete accordion should compact automatically.

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
jQuery('#portslid').accordion({
collapsible: true,
autoheight: false,  
alwaysOpen: false,
active: false,
animated: "bounceslide"
//animated: 'easeslide'
});     
});
```

Comment: and your problem here is that ? it's not opening while the page is loading ? or Its not compacting after the page load ?

Comment: it's not opening while page is loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the accordion to be open at page load you should change the active option to the element that you want to be open :

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
jQuery('#portslid').accordion({
collapsible: true,
autoheight: false,  
alwaysOpen: false,
active: 1,
animated: "bounceslide"
//animated: 'easeslide'
});     
});
```

And then at the load you close it :

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('#portslid').accordion({active: false});     
    });
```

EDIT : The jquery accordeon does not support to be all open , but there's work around like here : [jQuery Accordion expand all div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558553/jquery-accordion-expand-all-div)

Comment: i want all the sections should open while the page is loading.when page finishes loading all the sections should close by self.