# jQuery UI accordion - expand all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, expand

I'm using below example code from Jquery website:
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
collapsible: true
});
});
</script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div> content 1 </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div> content 2 </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div> content 3 </div>
</div>
```

But now I need to add two buttons: one to "Collapse All" and another one to "Expand All".

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Accordion Expand/Collapse All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all)

Comment: As above, I'd refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903079/1856970 though are you sure an accordion is the best options for your project? They are designed to only be open one at a time. That's kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

/** HTML Code**/

```
<a id="collapseAll">Collapse All</a>
<a id="expandAll">Expand All</a>
```

/** Jquery Code **/

```
$("#collapseAll").click(function(){
    $(".ui-accordion-content").hide()
});


$("#expandAll").click(function(){
    $(".ui-accordion-content").show()
});
```

Comment: this question is about expanding/collapsing all accordions, not hide/show the container.