# How to open all accordian in click a tag using UiJquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

**How to do this functionality**

if i click `<a href="#">Collapse All</a>` than open `all Accordian` and **again click** this `Collapse all`

I m using **[uiJqueryAccordian](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)**

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/s5hAw/443/)

**html code**

```
<h1>My Accordina</h1>   <a href="#">Collapse All</a>
<div class="js_enrollment">
  <h4>demo section one</h4>
   <div class="">here some text here some text</div>
<h4>demo section one</h4>
   <div class="">here some text here some text</div>
<h4>demo section one</h4>
   <div class="">here some text here some text</div>
<h4>demo section one</h4>
   <div class="">here some text here some text</div>
</div>
```

**jquery code**

```
    $( ".js_enrollment" ).accordion({ 
    header: "h4",
    icons: { "header": "icon-plus", "headerSelected": "icon-minus" },
    autoHeight: false
});
```

**I m** **[finding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all)** **but not solve my problem**

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all.

Comment: Fiddle Demo is this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/s5hAw/443/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.ui-accordion-content').is(':visible') ){
        $(this).text('Collapse ALl');
    $('.ui-accordion-content').hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('Expand ALl');
        $('.ui-accordion-content').show();
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/s5hAw/444/)

Comment: @RohitAzad Though with a slight bug, I have added my answer.  go through which can be fixed.