# Expand all or Collapse all in stylesheet using Java

Tags: javascript, html, css, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have many XML files that I want to create a table of them as an HTML file and then show the result table. Then I use one `xsl:elemnt` to create cell of tables as:

```
<table>
    <col span="1" class="firstCol" />
    <thead align="center">
        <tr class="headerColor" >
            <th style="text-align: left" class="Test" >Test</th>
            <th > Start </th>
            <th > End </th>
            <th > Duration </th>
        </tr >
        <tr style="border: 2px solid black" class="fristRow" onclick="CollapseExpandAll(this)" title="Click here to collapse/expand">
            <td align="left">
                <b> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="attribute::name"/>                            
                </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <xsl:element name="tableRows">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="attribute::name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</table>
```

using this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
    function CollapseExpandAll(obj)
        {
            var tableRows = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tableRows")[0];
            var old = tableRows.style.display;
            tableRows.style.display = (old == "none"?"":"none");
        }
</script>
```

What does this code is that expand/collapse one table separately by clicking the second row. What I want to have is to have one button does the job collapse all or expand all at the same time for all table created in HTML (not each table by clicking). I googled through internet and find nice examples but I do not know how to localize them for my case. (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499419/collapse-all-and-still-have-the-first-accordion-opened-by-default)). May I ask your help? Thanks a lot in advance!!

**Update:**

Here is an example of my XML file,

```
<SquishReport version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
    <test name="tst_main">
        <test name="tst_start_app">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst2">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
    </test>
    <test name="tst_main2">
        <test name="tst3">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst4">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst5">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst6">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
    </test>
    <test name="tst_main3">
        <test name="tst7">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst8">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
        <test name="tst9">
            <description>  CDATA </description>
        </test>
    </test>
</SquishReport>
```

For each `test_main` I would like to have a table separately, then I will have three tables in my HTML file.

Comment: there is no open class in your code

Comment: @himanshu it was extra and is not relevant to this code. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works.

```
$('.fristRow').click(function(){
    $('.fristRow').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this thread.

[How can I expand and collapse a <div> using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460116/how-can-i-expand-and-collapse-a-div-using-javascript)

In your case, you would need to add a class to the table (if you want the whole table to get the effect). The code would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="tableClass">
<col span="1" class="firstCol" />
<thead align="center">
    <tr class="headerColor" >
        <th style="text-align: left" class="Test" >Test</th>
        <th > Start </th>
        <th > End </th>
        <th > Duration </th>
    </tr >
    <tr style="border: 2px solid black" class="fristRow" onclick="CollapseExpandAll(this)" title="Click here to collapse/expand">
        <td align="left">
            <b> 
                <xsl:value-of select="attribute::name"/>                            
            </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<xsl:element name="tableRows">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="attribute::name"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
    $(".tableClass").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $header.text(function () {
        //change text based on condition
        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that in this case you will need to have JQuery in your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this will be only for one table rather than 20 tables which it will be created from each XML files.

Comment: I think you just need to add the same class to all the tables - in your case, in the template where the tables are being based.

Comment: But I have only that one in my XSLT and then it will be created others by using XML files as HTML file. Then, actually I have only one in XSLT but many in HTML file

Comment: If you make sure that all the generated tables will have the same class (in my example, 'tableClass'), I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Would you please consider the XML file which I have added in "Update" part of question?