# How to exclude nested accordion in expand/collapse all function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to **collapse/expand** the root acordion is `#accordion1` using folowing code.
But at the same time I have to ignore/exclude the nested accrodion is `#nestedAccordion`.

I cannot get working properly it. Please, help.

```
function ExpandAll() {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').not('#nestedAccordion').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').attr({ 'aria-selected': 'true', 'tabindex': '0' });
        $('.ui-accordion-header .ui-icon').not('#nestedAccordion').removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
        $('.ui-accordion-content').not('#nestedAccordion').addClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({ 'aria-expanded': 'true', 'aria-hidden': 'false' }).show();
    }

    function CollapseAll() {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').not('#nestedAccordion').removeClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr({ 'aria-selected': 'false', 'tabindex': '-1' });
        $('.ui-accordion-header .ui-icon').not('#nestedAccordion').removeClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s').addClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
        $('.ui-accordion-content').not('#nestedAccordion').removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({ 'aria-expanded': 'false', 'aria-hidden': 'true' }).hide();
    }
```

**Html**

```
<div id="accordion1">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
   <div id="nestedAccordion">
    <h3>Section A</h3>
    <div>
       Text... 
    </div>
    <h3>Section B</h3>
    <div>
       Text... 
    </div>
   </div>     
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>    
    Text...       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all

Comment: @isherwood I have well working code. The problem is that I need to exclude somehow using jQuery selector the nested DIV that is accrodion itself so it has the same classes I am trying to use in jQuery selector.