# Expanding and collapsing all sections of a jQuery UI accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Got a project that requires an accordion, and needs an "expand all / collapse all" control. It works, but there are two issues:

1. If you expand all the sections, and then click a single section header to close it, it doesn't work. You have to click it a second time to close it
2. The header icon doesn't change when you collapse the section, despite removing the ui-accordion-header-active class

Yes, I have already read the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all). I don't want to roll my own, because the client is already using jquery ui accordions elsewhere, and I want to keep things consistent.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7k1stb6d/

And here is my js:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});

$(document).on('click', '.toggle-help', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('show-all hide-all');
    $(this).text(function (i, v) {
        return v === 'Expand All Topics' ? 'Collapse All Topics' : 'Expand All Topics';
    })
});

$(document).on('click', '.show-all', function (event) {
    $('.accordion .ui-accordion-content').css("display", "block").attr('aria-expanded', 'true').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
    $('.accordion .ui-accordion-header').removeClass('.ui-accordion-header-active');
});
$(document).on('click', '.hide-all', function (event) {
    $('.accordion .ui-accordion-content').css("display", "none").attr('aria-expanded', 'false').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    $('.accordion .ui-accordion-header').addClass('.ui-accordion-header-active');
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the second question first since it's the easiest. The problem was simply that you were adding a period before the class in the addClass and removeClass functions which was adding the period to the class list itself. Remove the period and it works correctly: `addClass('ui-accordion-header-active');`

First question was a bit harder. The accordion doesn't like to have more than one item active and messing around with the classes complicates all of this. Instead of using your add/remove class functionality on the clicks themselves it was better to add it to the accordion constructor and go from there. I borrowed the functionality from here: [jQuery UI accordion that keeps multiple sections open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479447/jquery-ui-accordion-that-keeps-multiple-sections-open) to figure out how to have multiple actives but keep the accordion. It injects the desired behaviour into the `beforeActivate` event:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible:true,

    beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
         // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
        if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
            var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
         // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
        } else {
            var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
            var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
        }
         // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
        var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

         // Toggle the panel's header
        currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

        // Toggle the panel's icon
        currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

         // Toggle the panel's content
        currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)    
        if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); }  else { currContent.slideDown(); }

        return false; // Cancels the default action
    }
});
```

Then the clicks themselves check for whether any of the items have been clicked already to avoid issues with the show/hide toggle. After that check it sets that item to be active via the active option (http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) which then goes through the `beforeActive` function now set in the accordion:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-all', function (event) {
    $(".ui-accordion-header").each(function(i) {
        if($(this).attr('aria-selected') == 'false') {
            $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", i);
        }
    });
});
```

I set it all up here: https://jsfiddle.net/7k1stb6d/7/

Comment: Wow, fantastic! Thanks Paul!