# Change setting in CSS when link is clicked using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have an Expand All button. I am able to have all div tags expand but not able to have plus toggle to minus (which is what happens when you click plus sign one at a time - it expands and becomes minus.) I think i need to somehow manipulate this tag `p.accordion:before` to change its "Content" setting, but how? Can i do it with javascript? This is the code. Please help.

```js
function expandAll() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  //enter code here
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var panel = elements[i];
    panel.style["display"] = "block";

  }

}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

p.accordion.active,
p.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

p.accordion:before {
  content: '\002B';
  float: left;
}

p.accordion.active:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button onclick="expandAll();">Expand All</button>
<p class="accordion">Section 2</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="accordion">Section 1</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="accordion">Section 3</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all

Comment: @YashSoni there is no jquery in OPs post.

Comment: What do you mean by _stops working after x many times?_
Maybe problem in `document.querySelectorAll('p.accordion')`? Try a more specific selector.

Comment: Thank you. I think there were other issues in my code. It works now. I am not sure what exactly was the problem - possibly something unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have class `active`. Just add it to all `p`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', expandAll)
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

function expandAll() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  var accordions = document.querySelectorAll('p.accordion')
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var panel = elements[i];
    panel.style["display"] = "block";
    accordions[i].classList.add("active");
  }

}
```

```css
p.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

p.accordion.active,
p.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

p.accordion:before {
  content: '\002B';
  float: left;
}

p.accordion.active:before {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button>Expand All</button>
<p class="accordion">Section 2</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="accordion">Section 1</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="accordion">Section 3</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```